# when using miltiple datasource hibernate envers are not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, datasource, hibernate-envers

When I use only one datasource, hibernate envers are working well(not using any config.java. just set application.properties). But Using multiple datasource(with config.java, same DB, different user), envers are not working and logged oracle error message ORA-00942.
audited table is in DB#1. How can I do?

spring boot 1.5.6

**application.properties**

```
#################################
#   DataBase #1 (Default)
#################################
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
spring.datasource.username=id_1
spring.datasource.password=pw_1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

#################################
#   DataBase #2(Additional)
#################################
db2.datasource.initialize=true
db2.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
db2.datasource.username=db_2
db2.datasource.password=pw_2
db2.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

**config.java**

```
package com.dev;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@Configuration
public class DataBaseConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource defaultDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "defaultEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {


        return builder.dataSource(defaultDataSource())
                .packages("com.dev.core.**", "com.dev.ext.**")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "defaultTransactionManager")
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory(builder).getObject());
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages= {"com.dev.core.**", "com.dev.ext.**"},
            entityManagerFactoryRef = "defaultEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "defaultTransactionManager")
    static class DefaultJpaRepositoriesConfig {
    }

    /*Additional Data Source - NCRM*/
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "db2.datasource")
    public DataSource ncrmDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "ncrmEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ncrmEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {

        return builder.dataSource(ncrmDataSource())
                .packages("com.dev.ext.ncrm.*.domain")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "ncrmTtransactionManager")
    PlatformTransactionManager ncrmTransactionManagerMain(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(ncrmEntityManagerFactory(builder).getObject());
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableJpaRepositories(
            basePackages="com.dev.ext.ncrm.*.repo",
            entityManagerFactoryRef = "ncrmEntityManagerFactory",
            transactionManagerRef = "ncrmTtransactionManager")
    static class ncrmJpaRepositoriesConfig {
    }
}
```

**defaultDO.java**

```
package com.dev.core.domain;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ColumnResult;
import javax.persistence.ConstructorResult;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedNativeQuery;
import org.hibernate.envers.AuditTable;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_category")
@Audited
@AuditTable("tx_category_audit")
public class CategoryDO {

    //codes 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

First add hibernate dialect at application.properties file like below for both data source:

```
spring.datasource.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.secondDatasource.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Then Please rewrite the configuration like below

```
package com.multisource.poc.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.hibernate.dialect}")
    private String oracleDialect;

    @Value("${spring.secondDatasource.hibernate.dialect}")
    private String postgresDialect;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "oracleDB")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource oracleDataSource() {
        return  DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "oracleEM")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean oracleEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", oracleDialect);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = builder
                .dataSource(oracleDataSource())
                .packages("entitypackageOne")
                .persistenceUnit("oraclePU")
                .build();

        emf.setJpaProperties(properties);

        return emf;

    }


    @Bean(name = "postgresDB")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.secondDatasource")
    public DataSource postgresDataSource() {
        return  DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "postgresEM")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean postgresEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", postgresDialect);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = builder
                .dataSource(postgresDataSource())
                .packages("entitypackageTwo")
                .persistenceUnit("postgresPU")
                .build();

        emf.setJpaProperties(properties);

        return emf;
    }


}
```

Now you have two different EntityManager to use. The sample would be like

```
@Repository
public class OracleDao implements InterOracle {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public OracleDao(@Qualifier("oracleEM") EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

}


@Repository
public class PostgresDao implements InterPostGres{
    private static final Logger LOG
            = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PostgresDao.class);


    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public PostgresDao(@Qualifier("postgresEM") EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

}
```

This is how my application is working using two different datasource.

Comment: Thanks to your answer! But it is not working too. First, When I delete DefaultJpaRepositoriesConfig() and ncrmJpaRepositoriesConfig() method in config.java, an error occurs like [Duplicate '@ConfigurationProperties` definition for prefix 'db2.datasource'.] Second, delete like first, an error occurs like [Field catRepo in com.dev.ext.audits.repo.CatAuditRepo required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.].

Comment: This doesn't seem to be answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

Does user `db_2 / pw_2` have the required permission to access the DB?

Comment: I think they have. Because db_1 & db_2 are same DB but different User. I can read db_1's & db_2's data. But only audit table's data in db_1 are not loaded.(400 error + ORA-00942). What is the way of checking/setting the required permission?

Comment: You are trying to log into the same DB using different credentials, (id_1 / pw_1 and db_2 / pw_2).

Try logging in using SQL Developer client for instance, using both accounts and try to select from one of the Audit tables.

Comment: I try connecting both users and select audit tables.(db_1 : select * from db_2.table/db_2 : select * from db_1.audit_table) In SQL Developer, that queries works. What can I consider other setting?

Comment: you are not selecting from the same tables: select * from db_2.table   /     select * from db_1.audit_table

Comment: [db_1 : audit_tbl // db_2 : tbl]
[logging in db_1] - select * from db_1.audit_tbl / select * from db_2.tbl
[logging in db_2] - select * from db_1.audit_tbl / select * from db_2.tbl
I tested and both work...

Comment: Aren't you selecting from different tables when you do:
select * from db_1.audit_tbl
select * from db_2.tbl 

It has been a while since I last used envers, but if I remember correctly, for a given table table tablex, assuming the envers suffix is _audit, the related envers table would be tablex_audit.

You would have to make sure the 2 accounts you are using have privileges to access the tables and their associated _audit tables.